# How can I format the output of stat to contain the null character?

Tags: binary, coreutils, stat

I want to delimit file paths by using the null character (NUL, \0, ...) just like for example find -print0 does.

I'm using bash and I tried the following without success:

```
find $1 -print0 > dircontent
cat dircontent | xargs -0 stat --format="%X %Y %Z %f %u %g %i %h \0%n\0%s" > dirstats
```

Seems like I', getting a literal '\' and a '0' instead of a null character.

Comment: It works fine. The \0s are in your format string.

Comment: They're not nulls though. When I do `cat dirstats` they show as `\0` and when I do `cat -v dirstats` they show as `\0` too. Real null characters would not show with `cat` and would be displayed as `^@` with `cat -v`.

Comment: For me `cat dirstats` the nulls are removed when drawn on the terminal. `cat -v dirstats` gives me with `^@`. Can you run the first line again. Also what are the filenames. If they end with \0 (A \ and a 0) then you would see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--format` only parses percent escapes and adds a newline at the end. `--printf` also parses backslash escapes and doesn't add a trailing newline.

```
<dircontent xargs -0 stat --printf="%X %Y %Z %f %u %g %i %h \0%n\0%s\0" > dirstats
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `//` as a delimiter and then `sed -in 's/\/\//\x0/g' dirstats` to get what I want. I'd still prefer a less hackish solution.